# Setting visible scale ranges for summary widget clusters in Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I am currently working with Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS Developer Edition 2.4 to create a number of web maps for my company. One in particular uses the summary widget to show clusters of features at specific locations (see image).

[image]

The clusters of course can be turned on and off however I have been presented with two specific issues.

1. I cannot find a way to only show the clusters at specific visibility scale ranges. I would like it so the summary clusters turned off at a specific map scale, so the user doesn't have to turn the widget off and on regularly.
2. I would like to have both the summary widget and bookmark widget open on launch. This currently doesn't seem to work as the summary widget overrides the bookmark widget. If you set the summary widget to off, the bookmark tab shows on launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from our clever tech support guys, I've got the first point working.

In the ...\server\apps\11\widgets\Summary\ClusterLayer.js" file, the following code can be added to the '// cluster features' block, starting from approx. line 66.

```
      var scaleLevel = this._map.getLevel();
      if (scaleLevel > 7){return;}
```

Where 7 is the [zoom level scale](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/03/19/how-can-you-tell-what-map-scales-are-shown-for-online-maps/). This will only show the clusters at scales 1-7.